# Acessing variables inside function, Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, variables, math, web

i have a question. Or more like a task or whatever you could call it.
See i got this thing i want to do, but i need to access a variable inside a function, i know this has been asked before, but i just couldnt figure it out.
Actually i got two questions.

I am trying to make a form, where a user is presented with two random numbers, and he then has to answer what the sum of these two numbers is.
This is my code:

HTML

```
<button class="Btn" id="check" onclick="check()">Check!</button>
<button class="Btn" onclick="newCalculation()">New Calculation</button>
<label id="question"></label>
<input id="answerBox" class="txtBox" type="text"></input>
```

This is two buttons, a label and a textbox. The first button makes a new calculation, the second one checks to see if the value of the textbox is equal to the answer of the calculation. The label is for the calculation to show.

This is the Javascript for the New calculation button:

```
function newCalculation() {
var firstnumber, secondnumber, answer;
firstnumber = (Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1)*10+(Math.floor(Math.random()*10));
secondnumber = (Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1)*10+(Math.floor(Math.random()*10));
answer = firstnumber + secondnumber;
document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = firstnumber + " + " + secondnumber + " = ";
}
```

As far as i can see this is all rigth. But when i have to check if it's correct, i can't access the variables.

Checkbutton

```
function check() {
  if (document.getElementById("answerBox").innerHTML === newCalculation.answer) {
    alert("Correct!")
}
  else {
    alert("Wrong!")
};}
```

In the console log it says the right value with the textbox, but 'undefined' with the answer variable. If i remove the "newCalculation." it just says that the variable is undefined.
I'm just interested in knowing how to get around this, and have all this working. If you could give a full code example, it'd be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `input` is self closing tag, It does not have opening/closing tag, something like

**should be**

```
<input id="answerBox" class="txtBox" type="text">
```

instead of

```
<input id="answerBox" class="txtBox" type="text"></input>
```

You should get the value which will be compared from input tag something like this.

```
var compareVal = document.getElementById("answerBox").value;
```

**Updated**

When you want to share the variable, it's good practice to create class and it's relative properties and methods, you can access it's property on paritcular method you want, something like in your case.

javaScript

```
var calc = function (){
    this.answer =""; //can access on newCalculation() and check() 

    this.newCalculation = function () {
        var firstnumber, secondnumber, 
        firstnumber = (Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1)*10+(Math.floor(Math.random()*10));
        secondnumber = (Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1)*10+(Math.floor(Math.random()*10));
        this.answer = firstnumber + secondnumber;
        document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = firstnumber + " + " + secondnumber + " = ";
    },

    this.check = function() {
       var checkedVal = parseInt(document.getElementById("answerBox").value, 10);
        if (checkedVal === this.answer) {
            alert("Correct!");
        }else {
            alert("Wrong!");
       }
    }
}

var myCal = new calc(); //creating object by calling class/constructor

function checkAll(action){
    if(action == 'check'){
        myCal.check();
    }

    if(action == 'newCalc'){
        myCal.newCalculation();
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="Btn" id="check" onclick="checkAll('check')">Check!</button>
<button class="Btn" onclick="checkAll('newCalc')">New Calculation</button>
<label id="question"></label>
<input id="answerBox" class="txtBox" type="text" value="20"/>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7f4yQ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a function in JavaScript in no other block, it belongs in the global scope, and hence the variable `newCalculation` exists with the type `function`

What I would recommend is making it simple and declare

```
     var answer;
```

in the global scope - meaning not in any function. Then when you do the comparison in `check()` just compare with `answer` not `newCalculation.answer`

Comment: I Got so far, but i want it to do a new nummer everytime i Call the funktion?